# C#でVisual Studioを使わずに参照の追加がしたい

Tags: c#

ブラウザを使えない環境でC#を使いたいと思っているのですが、Visual Studioを使わずに参照の追加をする方法がありますか。具体的にはMS Wordの文字列を取得して処理したいと思っています。もしも、参照の追加を使わずにWordファイルを操作出来る方法があればそちらでも構いません。

Comment: 質問文を推敲してください。タイトルでは「参照の追加がしたい」と言っていますが末尾では「参照の追加を使わずに」となっています。どちらを求めているのか第三者にはわかりません。「参照の追加」は手段でしかなく、真に求めるのは別の何かだったりしませんか？ （例えばWord未インストール環境でも実行したい、とか？）

Comment: Visual Studioを新たにインストールできない環境でメモ帳でC#を使いたいと思っています。参照の追加をメモ帳で実現出来る方法があればそれがベストなのですが、それ以外の方法でMS Wordのファイルを操作出来る方法があれば、その方法も知りたいです。そもそもVisual Studioの「参照の追加」が何をしているのかもよく分かっていないので、それも教えて頂ければ最高です。Visual StudioでWordファイルを操作するには参照の追加でMicrosoft.Office.Interop.Wordを追加する様なのですが、それをメモ帳で実現したいです。参照の追加をメモ帳で実現する方法が分かれば他のプログラムでも応用できるのではないかと考えています。

Comment: 開発環境と実行環境を区別して考えてください。実行環境に制限があるのは構いませんが、制限のない開発環境で開発を行いそこで作成された実行ファイルを実行環境に持ち込むべきです。

Comment: 今の職場がウェブブラウザを使えない環境で業務の簡素化をしたいと思っています。休みの日にプログラムを修正して職場にもっていってもいいのですが、USBもあまり使いたくないしクラウドやメールも使えません。その状況で開発環境と実行環境を分ける術を私は知りません。なのでできれば仕事の合間にプログラムを作れればと思っています。もともと極めてアナログな職場で徐々に業務の簡素化を図り今に至っています。

Comment: 貴方の要望するようなことは、出来るかもしれませんが、そのためには多くの課題解決と知識習得が必要になるでしょう。少なくとも、貴方自身が何を如何したいのか、そのためには何が課題なのか、最初の(そして次、その次の)ステップは何か、といったことを(最初の課題だけでも)過不足無く明確に説明できるようにならないと、他者が助言することは難しいですね。質問記事とコメントの内容だと、1つの文の中でも考える対象が脈絡無く変わってしまったりしていて、何か裏技的なコストダウン方法を狙っているようですが、それは正統的な開発環境を入手して作業するよりも遥かに深く広く高度な知識と技術が必要に見えます。

Comment: Visual Studioを使わずにC#でWordファイルを操作したいという点については違ってないと思います。また、参照の追加が何をしてるのかについても知りたかったので大きくブレていないとは思います。ただ、それが今の知識レベルでは実現困難という事が分かりました。PowerShellで思っている事が出来そうでしたからそちらの方向で考えてみようと思います。

Comment: やりたいことがWordの操作であれば、Wordがインストールされている環境でしたらVBAが使用できるはずです。こちらの方が事例も豊富ですし、もともと今回の目的のような機能を実現するために用意されているものですので、VBAを使われてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: VBAでは実現出来ていますのでPower Shellでやってみたいと思います。

Comment: VBAで実現できているのであればある程度の業務の簡素化も実現できているのかと思われます。その上で、何を改善したいのかを明確にする必要があると思います。単に言語を（VBA→PowerShell / C#等へ）変更したいだけですか？

Comment: 他の方の疑問が当然な気はしますが、C#プロジェクトに参照の追加をしたいというのならば、.csprojファイルを編集すれば良いでしょう。テキストエディタで開いてReferenceタグ辺りを見てください。

Comment: Sayuriさん、ありがとうございます。最近、C#を勉強していてこれでやったらどうだろうと思っていた時に参照の追加で躓いたので、参照って何だろうと思ったのがそもそもの起こりです。調べてみても参照の追加ありきの説明しか見つかりませんでした。Visual Studioで参照の追加をしたプロジェクトとしてないプロジェクトを見比べてみても何が違うのかも分かりませんでした。とても理解不能な事であれば諦めも付くのですが、参照が何なのかを知る事が出来れば満足です。

Comment: Kamataさん、ありがとうございます。.csprojファイルですね。後ほど確認してみます。

Comment: @RyouKameda 「参照って何だろうと思った」であれば、質問文を修正してください。「Visual Studioなし」はやはり手段でしかなく、本当に知りたかったのは「参照の仕組みが知りたい」なのではありませんか？ 答えてほしい内容を質問するところまでが質問者の責務です。

Comment: 何が伝わりにくかったのかよく分かりません。私が知りたかったのはあくまでもVisual Studioが使えない環境でC#を使ってMS Wordのファイルを操作する手段で全く標題と異なりません。もしもそれが私には理解できないほど高度なことであれば、代替案として他の手段でも構いませんという趣旨で投稿させていただきました。参照の仕組みを知ったところでそれを実装できるとは到底思えません。参照の追加をする手段を知ることで参照とは何かを知りたいとは思っていました。ですのであくまで私が知りたかったのはVisual Studioを使わずに参照の追加をするで間違いありません。この議論は私の疑問を明確にするものではないのでこれで終了します。でも、C#で参照の追加をする手段を教えてくださる方がいらっしゃれば引き続きお願いしたいと思います。

Comment: 典型的な [XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701) に陥っている気がします。

Comment: 多分ネットが繋がっていないサーバー室等で開発されてて…というような感じだと推測しますが「USBもあまり使いたくないし」ということで1度くらいは使ってもよいかということでしたら
vs codeを持って行ってはどうでしょうか？オフラインでも使う方法がありますし
ポータブルモードならインストールもいらないです。
持っていくだけなら1回USBを使うだけで済むので。
もしOSがめちゃくちゃ古くて…とかだったらダメですが。

Comment: USBを使いたくないと言うのにはシステム的な意味もありますが、私が使うと他の人に使う事を禁止する事も出来なくなると言うことでもあります。もしもUSBを使った後に、直接的に関係が無かったとしてもPCが今までと違った挙動をしてしまった時はそこを疑わなくてはいけなくなります。また、Visual Studioをインストールしない状況でどこまで出来るか、代替案は無いのかも含めて考えたかったので投稿しました。

Comment: インストールしないでという話のようだったので、インストールしないで使えるポータブルモードの代替案を出したつもりだったのですが…
「使いたくない」ではなく「使わない」なら最初からそう言っといて欲しかったです。
他のコメント書かれた方と衝突するような感じに見えたので温和な雰囲気で案を出したつもりでしたが…
すみません、わざわざ代替案提示した自分がバカでした。以後関わらないように致します。

Comment: kisetuさん、不快に思われたのであれば申し訳ありません。USBを使うということに私が思っているほど皆さん抵抗がないのですかね？私としては当然タブーというか、使わないように促さなければいけないものだと思ってました。ですので元々USBを使うということを想定していませんでした。別にkisetuさんのご提案を否定したつもりはなく、こちらの現状報告としてコメントしたのですが折角代替案をいただいたのに本当に申し訳ありませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

参照の追加は、まあ端的には
https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/help/addreference.html
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/lib-compiler-option
でもこの挙動を理解するには Visual Studio がないと困難かもしれないっス

コマンドプロンプト上でコンパイルするのに毎回コマンドラインを手で打つのはあり得ないし、であれば `MSBuild` とか `make` とか支援ツールを導入する必要がありそうだし、それならば最初から Visual Studio を入れちゃうほうが楽そうだし、ってことで。敢えていばらの道を進みたいなら止めませんけど、費用対効果が低すぎてお勧めできないっス。

Comment: 質問文にはWordとありますが、その場合には回答に挙げられた機能だけでは完結しません。なので何が知りたいかが重要だったのですが、質問文を完成させる気がないらしいので答えようがなくなってます…。

Comment: まあ Word にこだわらずに「参照を追加」だけだったらこういうこともできるってことで。 csc.exe は Windows に付属してますし、そういう意味では Visual Studio なしでも C# 開発できなくはないんですが（お勧めしないあたりは変わらず）

Comment: Sayuriさん、だから何度も申し上げている様に私が知りたいのはタイトルに記載した事です。それ以上でもそれ以下でもありません。知らないのであればコメントしなければいいのに…。

Answer (score 0):

774RRさん、ありがとうございます。ようやく明確なご意見が頂けました。Visual Studioなり、MSBuildやmakeなどのツールを導入せずに参照の追加を実現しようとすると、余計な労力が必要になり効率的でないと言う事ですね。いずれも導入しようとするとインターネット接続やUSB接続は避けられませんものね。ご提示頂いたサイトは後ほどじっくり読み込みたいと思います。これまでのご意見を基に上に相談し、Visual Studioをインストールする事への許可を貰えないかも含めて、対応策を考えて行きたいと思います。不快に思われた部分が多かったと思いますが、皆さんありがとうございました。でも、参照の追加が何をしているかについてはやはり気になりますので、私なりに調べてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

通常の参照の追加は774RRさんが挙げられた動作で、最終的にはコンパイルオプション `/lib` の指定に相当します。
しかし、Wordには`/lib`で指定すべきDLLファイルが存在しません。そこを補うためにVisual Studioでは「参照の追加」の操作をした際、内部で[`Tlbimp.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer)を実行してWordのタイプライブラリから.NETアセンブリを生成しています。
「参照の仕組みが知りたい」なのではないかとコメントしたのは、このような情報を求めているか、求めているのであれば質問文に明記していただきたいという意図です。

`Tlbimp.exe`はVisual Studioに付属します。しかし、質問文の「Visual Studioを使わずに」が曖昧だと指摘したのは、他のツール、例えばVisual Studio Codeのインストールは認められるのか？ もしくは`Tlbimp.exe`を含む[.NET SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks)のインストールは認められるのか？ いずれも認められなくても別マシンで生成した.NETアセンブリを持ち込めるのか？ もしくはそれらを使わないアプローチでWordを制御したいのか等、手段はいくらでも考えられるため、目的を明確にする必要がありました。

---

> Sayuriさん、だから何度も申し上げている様に私が知りたいのはタイトルに記載した事です。それ以上でもそれ以下でもありません。知らないのであればコメントしなければいいのに…。

このサイトの最多回答者が知らないわけないでしょう。答えを導き出すために質問文を明確にすることを求めただけのことです。

Comment: タイトルの後の本文で、ブラウザが使えない環境でと申し上げています。一般的に社外で使用したUSBなどの記憶媒体は、社内のPCでの使用は望ましくないと思います。その様な中で社内のPCにVSCodeなどの様なツールを導入できる方法を私は知りません。また、sayuriさんからはじめてご指摘頂いた内容も、参照の追加を使うのか使わないのかということに対するご指摘と、参照の追加は手段でしかないというご指摘でした。私が知りたかったのは、その手段ですし手段を知ろうとする事に何が問題があるのかも分かりません。参照の仕組みを知りたいとは思ったものの、参照の仕組みを知った所でそれを実装できるとは思えない旨も既にお伝えしておりました。タイトルに書いた事は極めて明確で、何が明確になっていないのかが分かりません。今回ご提示頂いた内容についてはすぐには理解できそうにない内容ですので、熟読し理解できるように掘り下げて行きたいと思います。